# How to close dialog after posting JsonResponse success in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

After posting a Dialog Ajax Form by clicking the save button, I am unable to only close the Dialog and return to the original page.

Instead I am getting the Json response shown in a new page.

I know I am missing something but don't know where to look

My code is

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div id="dialog-model" title="Basic Model Dialog">
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog-model").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 900,
            height: 450,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000,
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000,

            }
        });
    });

    function editAccount(accountId) {
        $("#dialog-model").dialog("open");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/Edit',
            contentType: 'application/html',
            data: {id: accountId},
            success: function(content) {
                $('#dialog-model').html(content);
            },
            error: function(e) {}
        });
    };
    function updateSuccess(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
// GET: Account Edit
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var account = _accountService.GetAccountById(id);

    return PartialView(account == null ? new AccountDetailsModel(new Account()) : new AccountDetailsModel(account));
}

// POST: Account Edit
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(AccountDetailsModel accountDetailsModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "The attached file is not supported." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "The attached file is not supported." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@model BusinessOracle.Web.Models.Accounts.AccountDetailsModel


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Account", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
}, new { @id = "edit-account-form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="update-message" class="error invisible"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Account</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I was missing

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```